# How to process Sound with Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, audio, audio-processing

I have to implement the LPC (linear predictive coding) Algorithm with Java and quiet frankly don't have a clue where to start. Could someone please point me into a right direction.. I can't. of course, use already implemented algorithms from the java sound api (if its provides a solution).

Comment: sounds like homework to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java comes with an [AudioInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html).
You can get the inputStream by calling avax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File f).

The AudioInputStream has a read() method which reads the data. Probably, you will want to read all the data, do something with it and store it back to a file...

Comment: wow 15minutes! thanks a lot, thats all i needed ;)

and yes its homework.. i just needed some kind of start-direction as i never worked with sound before ;)